# PHP. Стоит ли на нем оставаться или найти более правильный путь?

Tags: javascript, php

Тема вероятнее всего от отчаянья.

Я более 6-ти лет разрабатываю на PHP, на среднем уровне (для джуна) знаю JS (ajax, работа с запросами и изредка создание различных элементов с помощью JS), пробовал писать на React и Vue (второе стал активно использовать). Написал множество CMS и CRM систем на PHP + JS, но сейчас мне банально скучно этим заниматься (возможно просто нет мотивации к чему то большему). Я понимаю, что у меня застой в развитии в плане программирования, включая программирование на PHP. Нет никаких курсов и литературы для моих знаний и я не знаю в какую сторону развиваться дальше, подумывал подучить JS и писать на нем (десктоп / веб), но опять же - нужно время, а стоит ли его тратить на JS? Я люблю ООП и строгую типизацию, которую JS мне не даст (да, есть TS).

Конечно, глупо было бы спрашивать - на какой язык перейти? Но хотел бы совета именно опытных разработчиков, либо бывших разработчиков на PHP, что вас мотивирует оставаться с этим языком, либо, почему вы перестали его использовать, на какой перешли и почему именно его выбрали?

Comment: два плюса - не прогадаешь )

Comment: Думаю слишком сложно будет для меня, но синтаксис C++ мне нравится, но душа к нему почему то не лежит. Слишком мало вакансий, а те, что есть - ищут сеньора, который разбирается во всем.

Comment: это да...может сам когда-нить доберуть до плюсов ) а так - ванилька жс, тайпскрипт и svelte (например)

Comment: Честно говоря, довольно странные вопросы для 6-летнего опыта, имхо. И что значит средний уровень для джуна? Я около 4 лет на php "сижу", начинал с cms, пошел в фреймворки; последние полтора года веду высоконагруженный проект на lumen/go + angular js (на всё том же ts) - скучно не бывает, постоянно новые фичи добавлять приходится, копать в разные стороны (в один момент уже php не хватало, пришлось знакомится с go и писать на нём некое подобие микросервисов). Нет неправильного пути ибо всё правильно если его правильно использовать.

Comment: @InDevX Под средним уровнем для джуна я имел в виду свои знания JS, которые не столь высоки. Я бы возможно с радостью так же поработал над крупным проектом, который заставил бы меня познакомится с другими языками и технологиями, но такой возможности нет. Всё, что я делаю - это однотипные заказы на фрилансе (laravel, laravel + vue, php cms, crm, wp и прочнее), по сути именно это и надоело (рутина), по этому часто задумываюсь заняться чем то новым, что будет интересно для меня.

Comment: _не поместилось всё.._ Всегда в свободное время пишу свой "тотальный" :D "проект", начиналось всё с блога, а сейчас функционала не меньше любой соцсети, в т.ч. и чаты, и звонки/видео, файлшеринг и прочее. Во многом нынешней работе мне помог именно этот мой "проект" (как знаниями, так и портфолио). Мне никогда не было скучно в php, но это не помешало, так же, за всё время изучить go, python, немного поработать с net, c#.. Если нет желания то надо искать своё, нет толку учить без него

Comment: У меня похожая ситуация, и я тот кто дерзнул, будучи PHP-шником, полезть в C++ и гейм-дев (точнее в графику, OpenGL, Vulkan, GLSL). Теперь вот ковыряю трассировку лучей на Vulkan. Графика - увлекательное направление, а C++ - язык богов. Всем советую. Но разумеется я не говорю о "смене профессии", мое дерзновение это скорее хобби, которым занимаюсь параллельно, но однажды хотелось бы сделать его основным своим занятием, конечно же.. не знаю, выйдет ли

Comment: @Zerxa У меня подозрение, что у основная ваша проблема именно в фрилансе и рутине. И думаю единственным вариантом будет найти проект покрупнее и в котором будут интересные, желательно нестандартные задачи, а не изготовление типовых страниц сайтов. А выбор языка зависит в общем то от решаемых задач.

Answer (score 2):

Это, конечно, прямая дорога к вратам в ад, то бишь к холивару, но давайте попробуем.

### Что мотивирует оставаться и отчего бывает скучно

#### Старые версии

Язык, как бы кто ни говорил обратное, развивается. PHP давно уже не тот, что был раньше (и на мой вкус, он вот только теперь как раз тоРт). У нас в компании PHP только что обновился с 7.1 до 7.4, и это прямо-таки заметный скачок. Конечно, если вы работаете где-то, где заставляют до сих пор использовать 5.3 и говорят, что ресурсов на апгрейд нет (мой тимлид работал в таком месте перед тем, как перейти туда, где работаю я), — это невероятно скучно, действительно. Выход: искать другую работу с более современным техническим стеком.

#### А может, дело не в PHP, а во фреймворке?

Язык, конечно, языком, но в случае PHP многие (почти все?) используют фреймворки, и они, как ни крути, накладывают весомый отпечаток на вашу манеру разработки. Мне сейчас приходится работать с Symfony, и, хотя я отдаю себе отчёт в том, что компоненты Symfony — прекрасные строительные кирпичики для приложений, я очень скучаю по простоте, удобству и лаконичности Laravel. Это чистая вкусовщина и субъективизм, я этого даже отрицать не стану (поэтому не надо со мной спорить о том, какой фреймворк лучше), но это таки может быть одним из краеугольных камней в вашем кажущемся застое и неудовлетворённости собой как программистом.
А может, вы разрабатываете под WordPress? Не хочу никого обижать, но тамошний код тоже весьма специфичен, скажем так.

### Что выбрать, если таки уходить?

Если бы вы не сказали, что любите ООП (я его тоже люблю, как ни странно!), мой ответ был бы однозначным: Go, Go и ещё раз Go. Модно, молодёжно, современно, веб из коробки, при этом куча возможностей для роста и поиска работы в разных областях от всё того же простого веба до каких-нибудь высоконагруженных распределённых систем. Сам сильно подумываю на этот счёт, уже давно присматриваюсь к языку. Но это не ООП, по крайней мере, не в том смысле, как в PHP.
Посмотрите на мобильную разработку, например, Kotlin (Android) или Swift (iOS). Может, это вас привлечёт (и отвлечёт тоже).

### И последнее: предупреждение!

Ни в коем случае не допускайте профессионального выгорания (почитайте о нём, если вдруг термин вам не знаком). Разберитесь в себе, помедитируйте, подумайте, что именно вас не устраивает, и меняйте это как можно скорее. И вполне возможно, дело тут не в языке.
Если хотите что-то обсудить или ещё услышать, добро пожаловать в комментарии.

Comment: Спасибо за столь интересный ответ! :)
Стараюсь трогать WP в самую последнюю очередь, к сожалению это иногда приходится делать, глядя на его стиль написания - всегда обидно, что он настолько популярен, но мы не о WP. Да, возможно выгорание, которое как то заставило забыть про разработку на пол года, было неприятно даже открывать IDE, не говоря уже о написании кода. В сторону Kotlin смотрел не один раз, но не хочется привязывать себя целиком к одной платформе (хоть и есть возможность писать на нем под десктом вместе с Java). Всё время смотрю в сторону JS как писал выше, но для меня он ужасен.

Comment: Заметьте, я JS даже не упомянул. его сейчас везде продавливают как якобы единственный язык для всего, но в моём понимании он... не то, чтобы ужасен, но я не хотел бы видеть его своим первым и единственным языком разработки.